# Selecting duplicates of a column using the frequency and occurring time of other columns in R

Tags: r, datetime, filter, subset, data-cleaning

I am using R and I have a data set with `ID`, `boarding_number`, and `time`. There are duplicates in `ID` and `baridng_numner`comlumns and for each row there is `time`. Some of the `boarding_nubmer` values are linked to different `IDs`.
this is a snapshot of the data:

```
ID  boarding_number  time              
 1     1234         2020-05-05 12:28:36
 2     7891         2020-05-12 11:21:36
 3     5432         2020-04-17 10:22:26
 4     1234         2020-06-11 10:11:36
 1     1234         2020-05-18 09:28:36
 5     7744         2020-08-10 09:11:11
 2     7891         2020-05-29 18:21:41
 6     7891         2020-06-01 11:21:36
 7     1234         2020-06-12 10:111:46
```

So, I would like to select those `bording_numbers` that have been linked to more than one (`>=2`) unique `ID`. And, I want to select the `ID` and `time_second_occurance` corresponding right to the second occurrence - the first time a boarding_number is linked to a different `ID` than the first `ID` it was linked to. I would also like to report the `number_occurances` of the boarding_number.

An outcome as follows would be my goal:

```
 ID   boarding_number  time_second_occurance      number_occurances 
 4     1234            2020-06-11 10:11:36                3
 6     7891            2020-06-01 11:21:36                2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(boarding_number) %>% 
  mutate(number_occuarances = n_distinct(ID)) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(ID) >= 2) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(ID)) %>% 
  slice(2)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   boarding_number [2]
     ID boarding_number time       hour     number_occuarances
  <int>           <int> <chr>      <chr>                 <int>
1     4            1234 2020-06-11 10:11:36                  3
2     6            7891 2020-06-01 11:21:36                  2
```

Comment: Thanks! what does `filter(!duplicated(ID))` do ? Because one ID cannot be linked to different `boarding_number`. There might be duplicates on both columns of `ID` and `boarding_number`. I mean same `ID` and `boarding_number` may be repeated.

Comment: It deletes the second observation with same `ID` and `boarding_number`. Ok, then the second line of your desired output won't be `ID == 6 & boarding_number == 7891` but rather `ID == 2 & boarding_number == 7891`, right?

Comment: Please consider [upvoting and/or accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found the answer useful.